# Is there an unsupervised learning method for determine the most common questions within a dataset?

Tags: natural-language-processing, unsupervised-learning, question-answering

I have a dataset consisting of questions from customers. I am curious of the n most frequent asked questions, regardless of the variation the questions might appear in.

Is there NLP methods for finding n most frequent asked questions?

Comment: How are you measuring "closeness" for questions? If you are looking for a general answer, you probably can use a pre-trained NLP model like bert - https://towardsdatascience.com/bert-for-measuring-text-similarity-eec91c6bf9e1. If you want something specific, can you provide more details?

Comment: How do you define variation of the same question and different question?

Comment: How I measure closeness, variation or distance is part of the question.  I know its common to use cosine to measure similarities in semantic spaces. But I'm curious if there were some methods I've overlooked for this problem.